flowtype doesn't work in alpine linux 3.20
I was using "flow-bin": "^0.129.0" with alpine 3.17 based python image without any issues.
However with alpine3.20 it doesn't work and gives this error:
$ flow
Error relocating /opt/app/node_modules/flow-bin/flow-linux64-v0.130.0/flow: posix_fallocate64: symbol not found

Here is the libs I have in my docker image:
FROM python:3.11.10-alpine3.20

RUN apk add --no-cache curl bash yarn

RUN apk add libstdc++ gcompat git gcc musl-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev make build-base


I would like to stay with Alpine instead of going with a different base image. Are there any missing libs to be installed to fix this issue?
